# Calling Sentry from Eloquent model yields error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I am trying to call `Sentry::` from within an Eloquent model. However, I am getting the error

`Non-static method Cartalyst\Sentry\Sentry::getUserProvider() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

Current code is below. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
namespace App\Model;

use Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\Eloquent\User as CartalystUser;
use Cartalyst\Sentry\Sentry;


class User extends CartalystUser {

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $hidden = array('password');


    public function __construct() {

        $users = Sentry::getUserProvider()->findAll();

        print_r($users);

        exit;
    }

    public function brands() {
        return $this->hasMany('Brand'); 
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: `getUserProvider()` is not a static method and you are calling it statically, try this `$sentry= new Sentry;$users=$sentry->getUserProvider()->findAll()` or add static keyword in `getUserProvider()` declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sentry::getUserProvider()` should be called from a controller, where an instance run.

If you want to extend a `Sentry\User` model, create your model like this :

```
class User extends Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\Eloquent\User { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is most likely too late for your question , but it might be helpful to other developers .

Answer : Just edit your namespace .

> **Change :** use Cartalyst\Sentry\Sentry;
>
> **To :** use Sentry ;